# Reordering a long data in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the picture below, I have an example of a long list of **x-y** coordinates of points in column **A** and I want to reorder and have them in column **C** in such a way that the new order follows the row numbers in column **B** (I have written 2 cells in column **C** as an example).
Is there any easy formula/script to do that or I have to type them all?
I really appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do, and fill down the formula:

[image]

---

```
=INDEX(A:A,B2)
```

---

However, you can also spill it,

```
=INDEX(A:A,B2:B13)
```

---

Another method to use is `XLOOKUP()` with `ROW()` function:

```
=XLOOKUP(B2:B7,ROW(A2:A7),A2:A7)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `INDEX` function:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10, B2)
```

And copy down.

[image: Reorder]